# Saving my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm sorry that I put this question because I think that is simple but I don't know how to do this think because I am a beginner.

I made a database in sql server management studio 2008 express and now I need to send this database to somebody by email.Where is this database saved?

I need to send it with all tables I created and with the diagram.

Should I generate a script or the database is saved somewhere on my computer.

Comment: You have it in your drive, I cannot remember the folder, but you can find it on google for "sql server default database folder"

Comment: Do they need the table definitions *and* data, or just the empty tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take backup of your database and you will get .`bak` file as a database backup copy then you can mail anyone and they can just restore it to use it.

In sql server management studio 2008 -> Right click on your database -> Task -> backup

[image]

To Restore the database right click on Databases then Restore database give the location
of `.bak` file.

[image]